# Proving $f_n \rightrightarrows f$, provided that $f_n \rightarrow f$, each $f_n$ is increasing, and $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness, uniform-convergence, monotone-functions

**Clarification: this is not Dini's theorem**.

The title is highly succinct but here is the task in full detail:

> Let $[a,b]\in \mathbb{R}$ where $a<b$ are reals.
>
> Each $f_n: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function. (Namely $x<y \implies f_n(x) \leq f_n(y)$ for all reals $x,y$ and all natural $n$).
>
> Suppose $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$. Show
>
> (a) $f$ is also increasing,
>
> (b) if $f$ is continuous then the convergence is uniform.

(a) was trivial, but I have been grappling with (b) recently. Today I think I managed to conjure up a passable solution, albeit a somewhat gory one. I present it below.

I am curious to know whether it has any logical gaps and if it could be improved upon and condensed.

---

*Attempt at (b)*:

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and thus uniformly continuous. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, upon which there is a $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that for each $x \in [a,b]: f\big( B(x,\delta) \big) \subset B(f(x), \epsilon) $.

To show uniform convergence we wish to exhibit a natural $N$, depending solely on $\epsilon > 0$, such that $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n (x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for each $x\in [a,b]$.

Take any $x \in [a,b]$ and draw $B(x,\frac \delta 2) \cap [a,b]$. The strategy next is to find a natural $N$ that works for all points in $B(x, \frac \delta 2)$. After that we will cover $[a,b]$ with open balls $B(x,\frac \delta 2)$ and extract a finite subcover, upon which we should obtain a natural number that works everywhere on $[a,b]$, thus affirming the convergence is uniform.

We know $f$ is increasing and $f$ maps $B(x,\frac \delta 2)$ into $B(f(x), \epsilon)$. Therefore $f(x) - \epsilon < f(x-\frac \delta 2) \leq f(x) \leq f(x+\frac \delta 2) < f(x) +\epsilon $.

Pointwise convergence is ensured at $x+\frac \delta 2$. Thus there is a natural $N(x+\frac \delta 2, \epsilon)$ such that $n \geq N(x+\frac \delta 2, \epsilon)$ implies $f_n(x+\frac \delta 2) < f(x+\frac \delta 2)  + \epsilon < f(x) + 2 \epsilon$.

But $f_n$ is increasing, so whenever $t < x+ \frac \delta 2$ and $ t\in[a,b]$, we have $f_n (t) \leq f_n (x+\frac \delta 2) <f(x) + 2\epsilon $. Of course we also have $f(t) < f(x) + \epsilon$.

Similarly we have a natural $N(x-\frac \delta 2,\epsilon)$ such that whenever $t > x - \frac \delta 2$ and $t\in [a,b]$ and $n \geq N(x-\frac \delta 2, \epsilon)$, we have $f_n(t) \geq f_n (x-\frac \delta 2) > f(x) - 2\epsilon$. Again we also have $f(t) > f(x) - \epsilon$.

So if $n \geq \max\{ N(x-\frac \delta 2, \epsilon), N(x+\frac \delta 2,\epsilon) \}$ and if $t\in B(x,\frac \delta 2) \cap [a,b]$ then we have $|f(t) -f(x) |< \epsilon$ and $|f_n(t) - f(x)|<2\epsilon$. Thus we have $|f_n(t) - f(t)| < 3 \epsilon$.

Thus if we go far enough beyond $N(x,\epsilon) := \max\{ N(x-\frac \delta 2, \epsilon), N(x+\frac \delta 2,\epsilon) \}$ then $f_n$ is within $3\epsilon$ of $f$, everywhere in the ball $B(x,\delta/2)$.

Now cover $[a,b]$ with $\bigcup_{x\in [a,b]} B(x,\frac \delta 2)$. Compactness furnishes a finite subcover, so say $[a,b] \subset B(x_1, \frac \delta 2) \cup B(x_2, \frac \delta 2)$. We showed earlier there are naturals $N(x,\epsilon)$ making the convergence "uniform" in $B(x, \frac \delta 2)$. The finite subcover therefore furnishes naturals $N(x_1, \epsilon)$ and $N(x_2, \epsilon)$.

Simply take $N(\epsilon) \geq \max\{ N(x_1, \epsilon), N(x_2, \epsilon) \}$. Then if $t\in [a,b]$, $t$ is in some ball $B(x,\frac \delta 2)$ and since $N(\epsilon)$ is large enough, $n \geq N(\epsilon)$ will ensure $|f_n(t) -f (t) | < 3 \epsilon$. Thus the convergence is uniform on $[a,b]$. We are done. $\blacksquare$.

Comment: I have added the tag `solution-verification` which seems relevant

Comment: @WilliamM. The cited Theorem is about a "monotonous sequence", not a "sequence of monotonous functions". Note that there is no notion of monotonous function on a general compact space since there is no order in general. (Btw, I also learned this Theorem as Dini's Theorem while I was a student, but it seems this is named that way only in the French literature: an Italian professor of mine once told me he didn't ever heard about this name)

Comment: I don't agree that this (as currently stated)  is Dini's theorem.  The assumption here is that $f_n(x)\leq f_n(y)$ while the assumption in Dini's theorem is $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ and the functions are assumed to be continuous (not monotone).   The original version of Dini is on pp. 110–112 of his 1878 book,   *Fondamenti per la teorica delle funzioni di variabili reali.*   I had to struggle with the Italian to find the reference since an editor insisted on the exact pages.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer during my initial posting, but I have edited my post now. No, this is absolutely *not* Dini's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof can be made much shorter and I believe more transparent.

By the uniform continuity of $f,$ for $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $m$ such that $|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}|<\varepsilon/2,$ where $x_k=a+{k\over m}(b-a),$ $k=0,1,\ldots,m.$ By the pointwise convergence there exists $N$ such that for any $n>N$  and $l$ we have $|f_n(x_l)-f(x_l)|<\varepsilon/2.$ Next let $x_{k-1}\le x\le x_k.$ Then $$f(x_{k-1})-{\varepsilon\over 2}\le f_n(x_{k-1})\le f_n(x)\le f_n(x_k)\le f(x_k)+{\varepsilon\over 2}$$ $$f(x_{k-1})\le f(x)\le f(x_k)$$ Therefore for $n>N$ we get $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$$

Comment: Thank you for your input! Interesting idea to partition the interval in that manner. The integer $m$ depends only $\epsilon$, correct? In which case, we are actually invoking *uniform* continuity? I am trying to complete your argument myself, but it is not clear to me how we have obtained an $N$ that works everywhere on $[a,b]$. The pointwise convergence gives us $m+1$ different integers $N$ at the $m+1$ grid points $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_m\}$. Are you tacitly taking the maximum of these integers at the end?

Comment: You are right. I was using uniform continuity of $f.$ The integer $m$ depends on $\varepsilon$  (and on$ f$ as well). Existence of common $ N$ is a general fact about finitely many convergent sequences., in our case $\{f_n(x_m)\}_{n=1}^\infty .$ As you noticed I am taking the maximum, or the sum of $N_m.$

Comment: Thank you. The $3$ in the denominator of $\epsilon /3$ implies three invocations of the triangle inequality in order to obtain $|f_n (x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$. I have been unsuccessful in obtaining $|f_n (x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$ from the antecedents. Could I ask you to elaborate how you go about obtaining it?

Comment: @kapython  Thanks for your comment. I have re-edited my answer. It is slightly better as I use $\varepsilon/2.$ At the end the point is that $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ belong to an open interval of length $\varepsilon.$ I hope there are no errors.